# Join two queries and use for numerical division

Tags: mysql

I have two queries A & B say, as follows:

```
SELECT SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(od.created_at, oc.created_at))) AS `sum (secs)`
FROM on_connected oc
JOIN on_disconnected od ON od.call_id = oc.call_id
WHERE oc.ext_num = 3205006;
+------------+
| sum (secs) |
+------------+
|    14      |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

and

```
SELECT count(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(od.created_at, oc.created_at))) AS `total calls`
FROM on_connected oc
JOIN on_disconnected od 
ON od.call_id = oc.call_id
WHERE oc.ext_num = 3205006;
+-----------------+
| total calls     |
+-----------------+
|               3 |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I'd like to use the results for a division operation in MySQL, like so:

```
SELECT A DIV B
```

This would give me a result of 14/3 = 4. What have I tried?

```
SELECT
(SELECT SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(od.created_at, oc.created_at))) AS `sum (secs)`
FROM on_connected oc
JOIN on_disconnected od ON od.call_id = oc.call_id) a

INNER JOIN

(SELECT count(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(od.created_at, oc.created_at))) AS `total calls`
FROM on_connected oc
JOIN on_disconnected od ON od.call_id = oc.call_id) b
WHERE oc.ext_num = 3205006;
```

The INNER JOIN syntax is getting in the way of my DIV operator though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it.

```
SELECT
  SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(od.created_at, oc.created_at))) /
  COUNT(*) AS `sec_per_call`
FROM on_connected oc
JOIN on_disconnected od ON od.call_id = oc.call_id
WHERE oc.ext_num = 3205006
```

You don't need two subqueries, because the criteria in both are the same. You just need to divide the two aggregates.

Also, `count(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(od.created_at, oc.created_at)))` doesn't really make sense. The `COUNT()` function just counts non-null values, there's no need to do complicated conversions like `TIMEDIFF` and `TIME_TO_SEC` in there. If you just want to know the number of calls, it's just the number of matching rows, which is `COUNT(*)`.

Actually, it can be simplified further. SUM/COUNT is just the average, and SQL has a built-in `AVG` function:

```
SELECT AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(od.created_at, oc.created_at))) AS `sec_per_call`
FROM on_connected oc
JOIN on_disconnected od ON od.call_id = oc.call_id
WHERE oc.ext_num = 3205006
```